# How to get the sub seconds of current time

Tags: c++11, boost

```
const boost::posix_time::ptime now;
boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

now.date().year();
now.date().month();
now.date().day();

now.time_of_day().hours(); 
now.time_of_day().minutes();
now.time_of_day().seconds();
```

I figured out how to get years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds using boost::posix_time::ptime.

But I can't get sub seconds of ptime. Is there any way to get milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by substracting scaled total number of seconds from total_milliseconds/microseconds:

To get *ms* use:

```
time_duration td;
td.total_milliseconds() - (td.total_seconds()*1000)
```

To get *us* use:

```
time_duration td;
td.total_microseconds() - (td.total_seconds()*1000000)
```

You need to change type of clock when calling `local_time` from `second_clock` (which is based on seconds precision) to `microsec_clock` to see *ms/us* different from 0.

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88862e3cb4c4af14)